# django session timesout within 10 seconds

Tags: django, apache, session, mod-wsgi, session-timeout

I've finally deployed the app. on production and the session timesout very quickly.
If I'm not continuously clicking on links, it'll **expire in 15-20 seconds**.

This doesn't happen in Dev. but again the setup is completely different.

Here is the setup I have in production -
**nginx + apache (wsgi) + django 1.1.2**
Backend is mysql.

The keepalive in nginx is "**keepalive_timeout  15;**" but the documentation says its for the process nginx launches and isn't related.

Following is present in the **settings.py** -

```
`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (`  
    `'django.core.context_processors.auth',`   
    `'django.core.context_processors.debug',`   
    `'django.core.context_processors.i18n',`   
    `'django.core.context_processors.media',`   
    `'django.core.context_processors.request',`   
    `'myown.custom_settings_context_processor.myown_custom_settings',`   
    `)`   

`SESSION_ENGINE = (`   
        `'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'`   
`)`   

`INSTALLED_APPS = (`   
    `'django.contrib.auth',`   
    `'django.contrib.contenttypes',`   
    `'django.contrib.sessions',`   
    `'django.contrib.sites',`   
    `'django.contrib.admin',`   
`)`
```

If any more info. is required, please let me know and I'll put it.
Any pointers about why this would be happening, appreciated.

Comment: I observed the "sessionid" cookie and I see the value changing continuously. Meaning, there is one cookie till I keep clicking links and when suddenly the session expires, there is a different one. I also see 4 other cookies - __utma, __utmb, __utmc & __utmz

Comment: I think I'm onto something !! I see that I'm checking if a user is logged in as this -- if request.user.is_authenticated(): This is failing randomly. So the problem might not be session, but request.user returning AnonymousUser.

Comment: Even though the cookies are enabled, I keep getting this for the admin "Looks like your browser isn't configured to accept cookies."

Comment: What is your cache expiry time set to? And what is your session cookie age set to?

Comment: The cookie age was set to default. Which I found was 2 weeks and shown correctly. The problem was that I haven't setup the cache system correctly, hence it timedout very quickly in prod. Have disabled it for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Anil from the django team.
Seems I haven't configured by caching properly.
Went to the default caching by commenting these lines in my settings.py and everything worked like a charm !!!!

`SESSION_ENGINE = (`
`'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'`
`)`

Thanks Anil & BrianHV